# UnexpectedValueException for file path that doesn't exist on production server, but exists on local machine

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-6

I'm new to elastic beanstalk. I'm zipping up my laravel project and uploading it to elastic beanstalk. I'm not currently using the CLI for any server administration, as I'm just trying to get use to electric beanstalk and how it works. I've configured the the root directory to be public and I get this laravel error:

> UnexpectedValueException There is no existing directory at "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thought-records/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied

The threads that I have seen about this all deal with homestead and not production servers. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to fix this? This `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thought-records/` is where I have my project stored on my local computer. I'm confused as to what's going on.

Comment: Delete the cache files in bootstrap directory and try again, it could be that Laravel is trying to output an error to the log using the path from local setup

Comment: So I deleted all of the files in the bootstrap directory and re-uploaded the project and now I'm getting 500 error

Comment: Better! now it's working

Comment: Don't need to delete all files from "bootstrap/cache", there is also ".gitignore" file which is needed. Revert that if you did that, and run "php artisan config:cache". Make sure that you've zipped only files/directories, which are not going to your git repository

Comment: @boolfalse I reverted. `php artisan clear:cache` and now I'm back to this error:

>There is no existing directory at "/Users/kylecorbinhurst/Desktop/thought-records/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied

It's just a different file path